# Rewrite URL condition - Remove category in URL and trailing numbers

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

What's the best way to rewrite URLs as 301 redirects with the following conditions?

**Sample old URLs to rewrite:**
 `/products/garments/red-yellow-polka-dress-00519`
 `/products/shoes/black-suede-boots-02508`

**Conditions:**

1. Change word `products` to `product`
2. Remove category from URL (example: `/garments` and `/shoes`)
3. Remove trailing number (including connecting dash) from URL (example: `-00519` and `-02508`)

**New URLs should be:**
 `/product/red-yellow-polka-dress`
 `/product/black-suede-boots`

Note that changes will be applied to an .htaccess file on a Wordpress environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products/[\w-]+/(.+)-\d+/?$ /product/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: You got it! Would you mind a follow up question? This is for the category URL. How about if the URL is `/c/garments/red-yellow-polka-dress-10_450` and I'm looking to rewrite it to `/c/garments/red-yellow-polka-dress` ? (The category is retained, and the trailing number has an underscore)

Comment: Then use: `RewriteRule ^(c/garments/.+)-[\d_]+/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you, however please note that `c` is changed to `category`, and that `garments` is a dynamic word (depending on the actual category)... How should it be written?

Comment: What do you mean by `c is changed to category`?

Comment: I mean to change `/c/` in the URL to `/category/`. I posted a new question for this if you'd be interested to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45728769/1399030