# Rewrite URL condition - Change particular string & remove trailing numbers

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

What's the best way to rewrite URLs as 301 redirects with the following conditions?

**Sample old URLs to rewrite:**
 `/c/garments-apparel/red-yellow-polka-dress-10_450`
 `/c/shoes-and-accessories/black-suede-boots-02_901`

**Conditions:**

1. Change `c` to `category`
2. Remove trailing number (including connecting dash) from URL (example: `-10_450` and `-02_901`)

**New URLs should be:**
 `/category/garments-apparel/red-yellow-polka-dress`
 `/category/shoes-and-accessories/black-suede-boots`

Note that changes will be applied to an .htaccess file on a Wordpress environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^c/([\w-]+/.+)-[\d_]+/?$ /category/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This makes it lose the category name of the URL eg: `shoes-and-accessories` or `garments-apparel`.

Comment: That must be due to bad cache in browser. On my apache this redirects `http://localhost/c/garments-apparel/red-yellow-polka-dress-10_450` to `http://localhost/category/garments-apparel/red-yellow-polka-dress`

Comment: You're right! I refreshed my permalinks & it's redirecting correctly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
[-_]\d+
```

to replace the trailing numbers with "" (empty string) [demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0Bbix/1)

then use the regex

```
\/c\/
```

and replace with **/category/** [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gjFaH/1/)